# What was the scholastic position on Monarchy?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, political-philosophy

I'm trying to look into the history of medieval political thought, and I am struggling with the scholastics, especially Scotus and Albert.  Does anyone know what their views were on Monarchy specifically or on the legitimacy of government in general?  I'm particularly interested in ways in which they may have differed from Aquinas and each other. Thanks.

Comment: According to [John Dun Scotus' Political and Economic Philosophy](https://books.google.ca/books?id=O3owAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA16&lpg=PA16&dq=duns+scotus+on+%22monarchy%22&source=bl&ots=tZzDAlCM7z&sig=8KO1Eh0FlVE6eQICG85Gtq4IxpU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwidosfCm6DeAhUnHTQIHU52DccQ6AEwBHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=duns%20scotus%20on%20%22monarchy%22&f=false), royal power came directly from God and the people.  Aquinas distinguished between "healthy" monarchy (monarchy+aristrocracy+democracy) and "perverted" monarchy (tyranny, oligarchy, and democracy as mob rule).

Comment: [Nederman reviews](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1407577) three books on medieval political theory (by Black, Blythe, and Burns). On Albert specifically see [Shall's Immortality and the Political Life of Man in Albertus Magnus](https://muse.jhu.edu/article/638326/summary).

Comment: Dante Alighieri's [De Monarchia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Monarchia)